# I'm putting in the numbers 1,3,5,7,0 the outcome should be 8 but I only get 7 since it's the fourth element, what do I do wrong?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ToisenJaKolmannenSumma {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            int number = Integer.valueOf(lukija.nextLine());

            if (number == 0) {
                break;
            }

            numbers.add(number);
        }

        System.out.println(numbers.get(1+2));
    }
}
```

Comment: How should it be 8? There is no value 8 in your list

Comment: Could you please explain why the output should be 8 if you input 7?

Comment: I'm *guessing* you really want `numbers.get(1) + numbers.get(2)` (and not your current `numbers.get(3)`)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. The whole question is in the title. I suggest that you come up with a shorter title and move the question to the body.

Comment: Sorry for a bad question, I'n really new to this. The outcome should be the total value of elements one and two, 3+5=8. numbers.get(1) + numbers.get(2) don't work.

Comment: "don't work" like "giving wrong result" or more like "reporting an error"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.out.println(numbers.get(1+2));`

Will evaluate to

`System.out.println(numbers.get(3));`

and return the fourth element.

To achieve what you want, you will probably want to do something like

`System.out.println(numbers.get(1) + numbers.get(2));`

Comment: numbers.get(1) + numbers.get(2) don't work. The outcome should be the value of 3+5=8. Sorry If I didn't make my self clare, I'm really new to this.